# Unable to create Team sites in an environment upgraded from WSS 3.0 to SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, site, team

I have successfully upgraded my WSS 3.0 environment to SharePoint Foundation 2010. Now, when i try to create a sub-site using 'Team Site' template, it gives me error saying 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. Some correlation id is also generated, but i am not getting any help by looking at the related details.

I am still able to create sites using 'Blank Site' template. Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 1):

A detailed information about your issue is explained in this link: http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2010/08/18/sharepoint-2010-products-upgrade-and-the-fabulous-40-application-templates.aspx

Please go through it and check if it solves your issue.

Comment: ChandraShekhar, please don't post duplicate answers. The other [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/101812/6382) is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom Team site template?

Could you please some addtional information from ULS logs by following [this post](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=353)

Comment: Below are the details for the correlation id i received,

Comment: could you please update the information from ULS logs?