# Not able to create Team SIte Sharepoint Foundation 2010 after an upgrade from WSS 3.0

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We did a migration from WSS 3.0 to SharePoint foundation 2010 using database attach method. The web site is running fine but I am not able to create any new sub sites using Team Site template. I am able to create a blank site though. It gives an unexpected error with different correlation ID every time.

This is full error on the SP Shell

```
New-SPWeb : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:10
+ New-SPWeb <<<<  -url http://infovm-bdca/aa -name "Test" -template STS#0 -AddToTopNav -UseParentTo
pNav
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share....SPCmdletNewWeb:SPCmdletNewWeb) [New
   -SPWeb], SPException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewWeb
```

Answer (score 0):

A detailed information about your issue is explained in this link: http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2010/08/18/sharepoint-2010-products-upgrade-and-the-fabulous-40-application-templates.aspx

Please go through it and check if it solves your issue.

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @ChandraShekhar: That did not solve my issue. I am able to use Team Site template for creating a new site collection on the same web application but not for creating sub sites.